# TypeScript - Can "Structural typing" and "OOP paradigm" co-exist?

Tags: object-oriented, programming-languages, type-systems, typescript

From [Type Compatibility - *Introduction*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html):

> Structural typing is a way of relating types based solely on their
>   members. This is in contrast with nominal typing. Consider the
>   following code:
>
> ```
> interface Named {
>     name: string;
> }
>
> class Person {
>     name: string;
> }
>
> let p: Named;
> // OK, because of structural typing
> p = new Person();
> ```
>
> In nominally-typed languages like C# or Java, the equivalent code
>   would be an error because the `Person` class does not explicitly
>   describe itself as being an implementor of the `Named` interface.
>
> TypeScript’s structural type system was designed based on how
>   JavaScript code is typically written. Because JavaScript widely uses
>   anonymous objects like function expressions and object literals, it’s
>   much more natural to represent the kinds of relationships found in
>   JavaScript libraries with a structural type system instead of a
>   nominal one.

---

From OOP paradigm perspective, below syntax is wrong, because `Person` doesn't `implements Named`

```
let p: Named;
p = new Person();
```

---

Like C# & Java, C syntax also respects *nominal typing*

---

[GO](https://golang.org/) syntax respects *structural typing*.

---

In TypeScript language, Can *structural type system* and syntax using *OOP paradigm* co-exist?

Comment: What precisely is this *"OOP paradigm syntax"*? Person *does* implement the Named interface, it just doesn't explicitly say so in its definition.

Answer (score 6):

Your assertion that

```
let p: Named;
p = new Person();
```

is wrong from an OOP paradigm perspective is incorrect.

The OOP paradigm does *not* require that the relations between types are expressed explicitly in the type system of the language you are using. This means that a *structural type system*, where relations between types are implicit can very well be used together with the OOP paradigm.

Comment: From OOP paradigm perspective, relation between types `Named` and `Person` should either be *is-a* or *implements*, for the syntax `let p: Named;p = new Person();` to be valid.

Comment: @user1787812 No. Let go of your Java/C# preconceptions.

Comment: @user1787812 From OOP paradigm perspective you do not even need a type system in the language, let alone static types.

Comment: @SebastianRedl What does No mean? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @user1787812 It means your comment is just wrong. From an OOP paradigm perspective, there doesn't even need to be such a thing as a "type", much less any specific relations between them. A unityped language is perfectly capable of being OO, e.g. by following the prototype object paradigm.

Comment: not only does it compile, but it also simply makes sense at runtime. Note this is how Golang works, Golang being structurally typed (altho Golang kinda sux).